# Write in Excel from Java NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, excel, swing, jar, apache-poi

When I try to add data to Excel from Java Ant, it shows `NoClassDefFoundError`, even that I imported all Jar files of Apache Poi. This is the Error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:org/apache/commons/io/output/UnsynchronizedByteArrayOutputStream

This is the code i tried:

```
XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
    
    XSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet("Sheet1");
    
    XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(0);
    
    Cell cell0 = row.createCell(0);
    cell0.setCellValue("HelloWorld!");
    
    
    try{
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("Result.xlsx"));
        wb.write(out);
        out.close();
        System.out.println("Done");
    }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

These are Jar imported files:
[image: Libraries Classpath]

Comment: I don't see any Apache Commons JARs in your classpath; if you continue to have problems, post text, not an image.

Comment: Do you mean that JAR’s in my classpath are wrong?@trashgod

Comment: I don't know; I can't see commons, and I can't scroll or expand the image

Comment: What happens [when you add all the dependencies of Apache POI and/or swap to using a dependency manager to do that for you?](https://poi.apache.org/components/index.html#components)

Comment: I would suggest spending a few minutes learning how to use gradle or maven - some build tool that works with pulling in transitive dependencies of jars - eg https://github.com/pjfanning/poi-gradle-example

Comment: @PJFanning in this project I am working with Ant

Comment: https://poi.apache.org/download.html - follow the binary zip or tar.gz link and that should have all the jars you neeed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved! It seems i needed to add dependecy to build.xml also after importing jar files!